# S3: Invalid bucket name - Bucket name must match the regex

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, error-handling

I try to list the objects in one specific S3 bucket using this code:

```
conn = client('s3')  # again assumes boto.cfg setup, assume AWS S3
for key in conn.list_objects(Bucket='arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket1/NAME/OF/FOLDER/')['Contents']:
    print(key['Key'])
```

But get this error:

```
Invalid bucket name "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket1/NAME/OF/FOLDER/": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:(s3|s3-object-lambda):[a-z\-0-9]*:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-.]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$"
```

I tried also some other ways (specifying the path to the S3 bucket) but nothing works. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
Bucket='my-bucket1'
for key in conn.list_objects(Bucket='my-bucket1', Prefix='NAME/OF/FOLDER/')['Contents']:
    print(key['Key'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get an error: `botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "prefix", must be one of: Bucket, Delimiter, EncodingType, Marker, MaxKeys, Prefix, RequestPayer, ExpectedBucketOwner`

Comment: @Tobitor Corrected the answer.